# Formatting datetime in Matplotlib x-axis labels

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, datetime-format, axis-labels

I currently have a dateframe that looks like the following:

[image]

If I print out the datatypes, time is datetime.date and price is numpy.float64. When I try to plot this using the following code, I get the plot below:

```
from matplotlib import dates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
plt.plot(df['time'], df['price']*100, color='royalblue', marker='o', markersize=8, linewidth=3.5)
```

[image]

I am confused as to why the x-axis is messed up and why the dates are being formatted as they are. Ideally I just want the dates to be as specified in the `time` column of the dataframe. Some other Stackoverflow posts suggested DateFormatter, so I tried adding the following line: `plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))`. However, I get the error 'list' object has no attribute 'DateFormatter'. Would love suggestions on how to fix the time formatting in the x-axis (ideally there should only be 5 ticks corresponding to the specified times). Thanks!

Comment: Don't call some list in your code the same name as a module you import. Or use `matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H')`

Comment: check the type of 'dates'

Comment: @Will the type of `dates` is `list` seen from the error.

Comment: I didn't save anything as `dates`. `dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')` is like doing `matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: I meant to ask check where 'dates' comes from. It is the wrong type.

Comment: @Will. I'm still confused with what you are saying and referring to. Can you please clarify your point. Are you referring to the time column, `df['time']`?

Comment: It's as easy as this: If you get the error `'list' object has no attribute 'DateFormatter'` then you have a list called `dates` somewhere in your code.

Comment: @JaneSully your error says that you're trying to access the 'DateFormatter' attribute on a list object. This implies that 'dates' is a list in your code and not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas' .plot() method to leverage pandas' formatting power. The method has a variety of options that are worth exploring [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Price': np.random.randint(20, 60, size=10),
                   'Change': np.random.randint(0, 10, size=10),
                   'Date': pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=10, freq='D')})

df.plot(x='Date', 
        y=['Price', 'Change'], 
        marker='o',
        markersize=8, 
        linewidth=2.0)
```

[image]

```
df.plot(x='Date', 
        y=['Price', 'Change'], 
        marker='o',
        markersize=8, 
        linewidth=2.0,
        color=['green', 'red'],
        subplots=True)
```

[image]